# Can useful second and third generation matter be synthesized?

Tags: science-based, physics, technological-development, materials

The standard model predicts that beyond the normal matter made from up and down quarks and electrons the exist [two other kinds of matter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_(particle_physics)). Second generation matter is made from strange and charm quarks and muons and is more massive than normal first generation matter. Third generation matter is more massive still and uses yet other kinds of particles.

I read that the later generations of matter decay into the first, yet I wonder if a K3 civilization could synthesize the later two generations. Would that matter be long lived enough to be useful? If yes, could "atoms" and "molecules" be constructed from it that would have useful chemical and physical properties?

Comment: Considering the highly speculative field in which this question is venturing, which sort of [tag:hard-science] are you expecting?

Comment: The decay times are on the order of nanoseconds or less. That isn't long enough for the particles to form atoms, let alone molecules. The one semi plausible exception to this is [strange matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_matter) but whether this is stable is not known for certain.

Comment: Well, maybe it'll be OK - these higher-order civilisations live by the mantra: live fast, decay young.

Comment: Here are some thoughts on subject https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/world-made-up-of-2nd-3rd-generation-particles.883560/  Post 11 gives what seems to be a good answer but I am not qualified to know how correct it is. Seems that similar elements and molecules could form but heavier elements are less likely to form?

Comment: Do you allow for this very advanced society to be able to play around with time such that nanoseconds to us becomes centuries for them? I mean, really, what is so sacrosanct about the  'second'? It really is quite arbitrary.

Comment: @L.Dutch Yea h, I adjusted it to science based.

Comment: @JarredJones Quite the interesting read, thanks. The particles sound quite weird.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond Sure, why not. This is going to be archailect technology anyway in my world if it is possible at all. Let's even, for arguments same suppose that they can slow down time somewhat using high Lorentz Factor environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're talking about higher energy quarks. Quick background for the uninitiated.

All our matter (fermions) are made of "up" and "down" quarks. These create things like neutrons and protons in groups of three. For instance, a neutron is an up quark and two "down" quarks, whereas a proton is two ups and a down.

Quarks are stuck in what's called "confinement". Basically, without being in a cluster, they aren't stable and will eventually fall apart. That whole "being in a cluster" thing does a thing called Quantum Chromodynamics to maintain containment, which is a fun topic on its own.

Side point: electrons are leptons. Muons are leptons, just like electrons, only 200x heavier.

The up and down quarks have muon counterparts called "charm" and "strange" quarks. Due to the above mentioned confinement, we can't accurately measure the mass of quarks, but our current measurements say that they're 100x - 1000x heavier than their electron counterparts.

Out of containment, charm and strange quarks only exist for a hundred millionth or trillionth of a second. Roughly. Just long enough to draw patterns in a bubble tank so we can measure them.

But, let's say they could be stabilized in containment to create muon level protons and neutrons, then build matter from them. What then?

We already have an example of what this might look like. Muonic hydrogen has been spotted in the wild. Not that the proton is made of charm and strange quarks, but the electron is replaced by a muon. This makes the entire arrangement much heavier, and the muon orbits the proton much closer than the electron would. This has been theorized as a shortcut to fusion power.

Extrapolating from this, you can guess a few things about muon-matter.

1. Much smaller
2. Much, MUCH more dense
3. More prone to fusion
4. Unwilling to interact with electron-matter.

For Sci-Fi Fun, you could do something that translated all of the atoms in a person's body into their muon equivalent, shrinking them down to the microscopic, but making them too dense to even notice normal matter. They'd still be affected by gravity, though, so you'd need to maintain constant thrust to prevent them from falling through the vacuum-like planet into the core and getting trapped.

For extra credit, there's a higher level of lepton called the "tau" that is another two or three orders of magnitude heavier than the above.

*I read that the later generations of matter decay into the first, yet I wonder if a K3 civilization could synthesize the later two generations. Would that matter be long lived enough to be useful? If yes, could "atoms" and "molecules" be constructed from it that would have useful chemical and physical properties?*

That, I think, is speculative enough that you could get away with almost anything.

Comment: Muon-catalyzed fusion... the universe hates us. If the muon were to last just an imperceptibly longer time before decaying, we'd have had fusion in the 1960s. As it is, the muons can get used for up to 2 or 3 fusion reactions, they're pretty recyclable, but it costs too much to make them for the power that the fusion releases. As for strange hadrons, those get a little scary in that they're apt to catalyze all other hadrons into becoming strange matter, or so I've read. Do not want. My guess is that strong K1s are able to synthesize strange matter, and they even have 50/50 odds of surviving.